# Conditions for admin get_current_screen action parent_file edit.php?post_type=page

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, conditional-tags, post-editor

I have a plugin that requires scripts to load for an admin panel in the page-attributes template drop-down on page post type.

However this script causes a `Uncaught TypeError:` on post post types which is a correct response and I understand that is not where my focus should turn.

Since this script is only necessary for the page post type, I believe the best solution is to conditionally format my script so it works as such.

Due diligence was taken to find and work this out, but without much luck. In `class-wp-screen.php`, 95, I find `$parent_base`, but I do not know how to format this to meet the conditions.

**My code to be modified**

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'gp_front_page_script');

function gp_front_page_script() 
{
    if ( isset( $_GET['post']) && isset( $_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' ) 
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('gp_fp', 
        plugins_url() . '/network-plugins/includes/globals/genpages/front-page.js',
       array('jquery'));
    }
}
```

**How do I format a condition to load a script on `edit.php?post_type=page` and not any other screen i.e. `edit.php`?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_current_screen()` to get details about the current screen. We want to hook on or after `load-edit.php` because `get_current_screen()` is defined just prior to this hook.

By hooking into `load-edit.php`, we guarantee that this code will only fire on the `edit.php` page. Then we check the current screen to see if the post type is a page. If it is, then we enqueue the script.

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'wpse_259909_load_edit' );
function wpse_259909_load_edit() {
  if( 'page' === get_current_screen()->post_type ) {
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'gp_front_page_script' );
  }
}

function gp_front_page_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'gp_fp', 
    plugins_url() . '/network-plugins/includes/globals/genpages/front-page.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
  );
}
```

If you need the script on the individual edit pages, you can add this hook too.

```
add_action( 'load-page.php', 'wpse_259909_load_edit' );
```

If you need the script on the new edit pages, you can add this hook too.

```
add_action( 'load-page-new.php', 'wpse_259909_load_edit' );
```

---

I'm not sure why the above code isn't working for you. I added the above code to a blank plugin on a fresh install of WP 4.7.3 and it enqueues the javascript in the head after jQuery.

The `load-edit.php` fires pretty early in the request, so maybe you're adding the hook too late.

You can use `get_current_screen()` in the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook as well, but you need to make sure you're on an edit screen. So this should work too.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'gp_front_page_script' );    
function gp_front_page_script() {
  $current_screen = get_current_screen();
  if( 'edit' === $current_screen->parent_base && 'page' === $current_screen->post_type ) {
    wp_enqueue_script(
      'gp_fp', 
      plugins_url() . '/network-plugins/includes/globals/genpages/front-page.js',
      array( 'jquery' )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I follow the logic in your example. Unless I am overlooking something (very likely), I cannot get it to work. The example code I was working with has been commented out.

Comment: I appreciate your input, but still no luck. I failed to mention this in my original question and it might have an impact (unsure); I'm running multisite.

Comment: I am on the correct page per your statement. If I omit `if( 'edit' === $current_screen->base && 'page' === $current_screen->post_type )` the code fires. The script loads with the other header scripts such as `jquery-core.js'. It fired off a few from the last to fire. I also changed the priority though that wouldn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: What WP version are you using? What page are you trying to load the js on? /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page - correct?

Comment: 4.7.3 - http://pasteboard.co/J4onLSDn8.jpg

Comment: ah. change 'edit' === $current_screen->base to 'edit' === $current_screen->parent_base

Comment: We may have made this a little more involved than necessary. Unless you can point out any concerns with the approach, this works: `if( 'page' === $current_screen->id )`